# Read API response in Angular2 & ionic

Tags: javascript, api, laravel, angular

I have successfully get it work to request data from API with http.get in Angular2. This is my http.get

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8001/v1/recent', {
      headers: headers
  })
  .map(res => res.text())
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data.total),
    () => console.log('API request complete')
  );
```

The API is based on Laravel, it will return data as follows

```
{
   "total": 8,
   "per_page": 50,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 1,
   "next_page_url": null,
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "from": 1,
   "to": 8,
   "data": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "John Doe",
         "author": {
            "isBlocked": "0",
         }
      },
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "John Doe",
         "author": {
            "isBlocked": "0",
         }
      }
    ]
}
```

How can I retrieve the JSON object above in Angular2? and all of it's nested array?

`console.log(data.total)` above is return undefined

Comment: Please provide more details about what you mean by "read". There are also several similar questions with answers. Did you try searching?

Comment: I just need to access the value of each key in JSON array. Yes, I have try to search but only a few result for Angular2.

Comment: "I just need to access the value of each key in JSON array" is quite generic. `jsonValue.somekey` or `jsonValue.somekey.someSubKey` is usually working fine.

Comment: I have updated the question above by attach the http.get request and how I try to access the key value in console log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json in your question is not properly formatted, you have an extra comma after `"isBlocked":"0"` (in line 15 and in line 22)

```
"author": {
   "isBlocked": "0",
}
```

which will make it a invalid JSON. Preventing Angular from parsing it correctly.

The other issue, you are calling `.map(res => res.text())` which will convert your response body to a string not an object. If you want it as a javascript object do `.map(res => res.json())` instead.

[Here is a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJiy8jMlSTAFrAoDgaaT?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks.. Finally I can understand better.